# Share multiple images from app to Facebook messenger?

Tags: android, android-intent, facebook-messenger

I want to send multiple images from my app to facebook messenger. I am able to send the image one at a time but when I am sending multiple images then error is coming stating: Sorry, Messenger was unable to process the file.

The code I am using is below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < selected_url_size; i++) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(selected_image_url.get(i));
                uri_list.add(uri);
            }
bt_messenger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                File f=new File(image_url);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+f.getAbsolutePath());
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                share.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
                share.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri_list);
                share.setType("image/*");
                share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(share);
            }
        });
```